# R Snowfall - Difficulty in implementing functions that call other functions

Tags: r, parallel-processing, snowfall

I am trying to teach myself how to use the Snowfall package, and I have run into the following problem when I try a function that calls a second function (this is a simplified use case of what I ultimately want to implement).

I currently have:

```
library (snowfall)
f1 <- function(n) { return (n-1) }
f2 <- function(n) { return (f1(n)^2) }
# initialize cluster
sfInit (parallel=TRUE , cpus=4)
# parallel computing
result <- sfLapply(1:10, f2)
# stop cluster
sfStop ()
```

but I receive the error message:

```
Error in checkForRemoteErrors(val) :
  4 nodes produced errors; first error: could not find function "f1"
```

However, if I then run lapply(1:10, f2) I receive the following output:

```
lapply(1:10, f2)
[[1]]
[1] 0

[[2]]
[1] 1

[[3]]
[1] 4

[[4]]
[1] 9

[[5]]
[1] 16

[[6]]
[1] 25

[[7]]
[1] 36

[[8]]
[1] 49

[[9]]
[1] 64

[[10]]
[1] 81
```

I ultimately want to use snowfall to implement a parallelized search procedures for multidimensional minimization problems, so will definitely need to be able to call functions from the main parallelized function.

Can anyone help with this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to export the `f1` function to the workers using the `sfExport` function between `sfInit` and `sfLapply`:

```
sfExport('f1')
```

This is the `snowfall` equivalent to the `snow` `clusterExport` function.

To export multiple variables, you can either use multiple arguments or the `list` argument:

```
sfExport('f1', 'x')
sfExport(list=c('f1', 'x'))
```

To export all variables in your global environment, use `sfExportAll`:

```
sfExportAll()
```

Comment: Perfect...thank you.  And for complicated implementations, presumably sfExportAll() would work?

Comment: @user2762408 `sfExportAll` is convenient if you want to export everything in your global environment, and the `except` option can be used to exclude variables that are not wanted.  You can also export multiple variables with `sfExport`, but you do have to name them all.

Answer (score 0):

I do not know the specifics of the snowfall package, but I do know that when doing parallel computing in R, you need to assume that each core you pass information to is a brand-new R instance.  Meaning, regardless of what you pass through your host prior to registering clusters, there is just the vanilla instance of R on your clones.

It looks like there is a call sfExportAll() which will put all of your global variables onto the clone instances.  I would try it out, but I can't run snowfall on my Windows machine.